# Javascript: wait for function in loop to finish executing before next iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, asynchronous, callback

```
$(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {


for (var i=1; i<=14; i++)
{
        setID(i); 
        checkField(i);

}

if ($('#pass_fail').val() != "fail")
{ 
//do something
}
```

This is what happens when I click on the submit button of a registration form.

**Order of execution I want:**

setID(1); 

checkField(1); //wait for this to finish

setID(2);

checkField(2);

setId(3);

checkField(3);

....

if statement

**Order of execution I get:**

for loop going from i=1 to i=14

if statement

checkField(i)s in random order

**Problem**: $('#pass_fail').val() has a default value of 'pass'. However through the loop checkField(i) might change its value to 'fail'. But since in reality the if statement is executed before checkField(i)s, the value of $('#pass_fail') always ends up being 'pass' and the 'do something' always executes.

How do I wait for checkField(i) to finish executing before moving on to the next iteration of the looP? Thank you in advance!

Comment: to convert async functions into synchronous ones, you might need to refactor checkField to take a callback of the next checkField.

Comment: So, `checkField()` performs a server request? Why not grab all fields together and check them all at once?

Comment: right, checkField() contains an Ajax call which accesses a php file with functions checking different fields.

The reason why I can't perform a single call for all the fields is because each call returns a different error msg, corresponding to THAT field. If a single checkField() checks all fields at once, then errors for all different fields will be displayed under the same field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming from your description of the issue that `checkField()` is making some sort of asynchronous Ajax call.  If you truly want to serialize the calls to `checkField()` so the 2nd call is not made until the first has completed, then you need to change the structure and flow of your code in order to do that.  The two common ways of doing so are either using a callback that indicates completion of a call to `checkField()` that triggers the next call to `checkField()` or the use of promises to accomplish something similar.

Here's an example of the callback mechanism:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var i = 0;
    function next() {
        i++;
        if (i <= 14) {
            setID(i);
            checkField(i, next);
        } else {
            // all checkField operations are done now
            if ($('#pass_fail').val() != "fail") { 
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
    next();
});
```

Then, `checkField()` would have to be modified to call the callback passed to it when it completes its asynchronous operation.

---

If you're using jQuery to make the ajax operations inside of checkField, it would be fairly easy to use jQuery promises to solve this also.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but in earlier response I didn't see any loop to wait for any other function or any inner loop execution to let it finish before next iteration.

With <kbd>**`JQuery 3.3.1`**</kbd>

Scenario:
`for loop` with `var i` will wait for inner other loop to complete before next iteration value of `i`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("p").click(function() {
    
     var varIDeferred = $.Deferred();
        var varJDeferred = $.Deferred();
        
        /*
        var loopJInside = function(j) {  
            console.log("j is : " + j);
            $("span").html($("span").html() + "<br>j is : " + j);
            varJDeferred.resolve();
            j++;
            console.log("j value after incr is : " + j);
            return j;
        }
        
        // call inside loopJ
        setTimeOut(j = loopJInside(j), 500);
        */
        
        var loopJ = function(valueI) {
        
            for (var j = valueI; j < (3+valueI); ) {
             
         varJDeferred = $.Deferred();
                $("span").html($("span").html() + "<br>j is : " + j);
                j++;
                varJDeferred.resolve();
                
            }
            
            varIDeferred.resolve();
            
            return (valueI+1);
        };
        
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; ) {
            
            varIDeferred = $.Deferred();
            
     $("span").html($("span").html() + "<br>value of i is : " + i);
            
            if (i == 3)
                break;
             
            i = loopJ(i);
        };
        
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p style="cursor:default;border:2px solid black;width:60px;padding:5px;">Click me</p>
<span><span>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this would help many one.